# For loop to add image to imagelist

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm cleaning up my code trying to short in some things

Now I've stumbled across:

```
  ImageList.Add(test.Properties.Resources.test1);
  ImageList.Add(test.Properties.Resources.test2);
  ImageList.Add(test.Properties.Resources.test3);
  ImageList.Add(test.Properties.Resources.test4);
  ImageList.Add(test.Properties.Resources.test5);
```

(There are 15 of these)
Was wondering if this could be shortened with a for loop

Something like:

```
for(int i=1; i<=15; i++)
        ImageList.Add(test.Properties.Resources.test +i);
```

Now ofcourse this won't work but I have no clue how to do this (if even possible)

Comment: Does `Resources` have an *enumerable* of these values that you can use?  The approach you're trying can be done with reflection, but that's often overkill for something like this.  Ideally it sounds like `Resources` should expose a collection of these images, and then you can just add in a loop over that collection (or perhaps even assign directly to the `ImageList` by transforming the collection with a `.Select()`).

Comment: It happened for times that I wondered if such thing exists.

Comment: if those where in any kind of collection inside your `Resources` object, that would be easy, but with the current design it is not possible in a clean way. You may want to update your design though, that would make it more future proof if you ever wish to extend your collection's size.

Comment: will ResourceManager work?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over resources via this code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;

...

ResourceSet resourceSet = MyResourceClass.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
{
    string resourceKey = entry.Key;
    object resource = entry.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection, to get the values:

```
public class Something
{
    public int Test1 { get; set; }
    public int Test2 { get; set; }
    public int Test3 { get; set; }
    public int Test4 { get; set; }
}


var thing = new Something();

var imageProperties = typeof(Something)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Test"));

var imagesToAdd = imageProperties
    .Select(property => property.GetValue(thing))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a property of type `IEnumerable<Image>` in the class of `Resources` object

```
public IEnumerable<Image> Images
{
    get
    {
        yield return test1;
        yield return test2;
        yield return test3;
        yield return test4;
        yield return test5;
        ...
    }
}
```

and then use it to fill ImageList

```
foreach(var image in test.Properties.Resources.Images)
{
     ImageList.Add(image); 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I just found out that there is a library for evaluating C# expression called Flee. Apparently you can use it to evaluate C# code so that you can loop over variable names, just like JavaScript, but the need for it most likely means a design flaw.

http://flee.codeplex.com/